# How to express as an equation DiD with multiple time periods with one treatment timing

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

Say a policy was introduced in 1 Jan 2013. I have yearly data from 2012 to 2019 and would like to implement a difference-in-differences model. I am exploiting variation in female intensiveness of firms prior to the implementation of the policy given by $ShareFemale_{i2012}$. $PostAmendment_t$ is a dummy variable which takes the value of 1 if the year is after 2013.

Would it be expressed as such:

$$
Y_{it} = \beta_1 ShareFemale_{i2012} + \beta_2 \sum_{t = 2012}^{2019} PostAmendment_t +\sum_{t = 2012}^{2019} \delta (ShareFemale_{i2012} * PostAmendment_t) + \alpha_i + \tau_t + \epsilon_{it}
$$

or without the time fixed effects $\tau_t$. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Why is $ShareFemale$ time-subscripted? What firms are “untreated” in this case?

Comment: It is subscripted because I am exploiting variation in female intensiveness of firms prior to the implementation of the policy that I believe affects female intensive firms more. Untreated firms are therefore firms with no female workers.

Comment: Were the male firms even eligible for this policy? Also, this equation is interacting the treatment dummy with indicators for *all time periods*, at least that's what the summation suggests. Is this what you want?